# Webpack not injecting vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'm using `got` as an npm package and importing it into one of my components. When I run everything through Webpack *only* in Safari does it say:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

After taking a closer look, it's definitely the `got` package that isn't getting their `const`'s converted to `var`'s.

I'm not really sure what to check to get this issue fixed.

From doing some research, I've came across to the proposed solutions such as:

- adding the `--harmony` flag to my build command
- have my `.babelrc` presets read `"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]`
- have excluded and included my `node_modules` in my javascript loader in webpack

All of which have not helped out.

Loader example:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loaders: ['babel'],
  exclude: /node_modules/, // also tried commenting out this line
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
},
```

Comment: How did you include `node_modules`? Have you tried `include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')])`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko very interesting. That did the trick for me! Is there anything else I should be cautious about including my `node_modules` that way?

Comment: You sacrifice speed by adding more files to transform during build step. I'd recommend you to be more specific and include only `got` folder from `node_modules.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including `src` folder (which I believe is a sibling of `node_modules` folder) adding or commenting `exclude: /node_modules/` makes no difference.

If you need to process a specific installed module you could use the following loader config. [Issue on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031).

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel',
  include: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'got')
  ]
},
```

Comment: My `src` folder is where I keep all of my components and containers. The only weird thing I noticed is when I include `node_modules` it processes all the needed javascript and puts them into a folder called 'Extra Scripts'. [Here's what I'm talking about](http://imgur.com/sgC5Ob2)

Comment: Hmm, thats unexpected. Not sure why would adding processing step affect the output. Have you tried to include a single `got` module?

Comment: I just implemented your suggested code in your answer and I'm still receiving the 'Extra Scripts' in the browser.